# Arquillian error while using with TomEE

Tags: jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I am getting below error while running Arquillian tests in embedded TomEE container

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:101)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:168)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.<init>(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.getInstance(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:76)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getJspApplicationContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:217)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.setJspELFactory(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:420)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.initializeServletContext(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:387)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1464)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 97 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is cause you used somehow the javax.javaee api jar and not  tomee one (org.apache.tomee:javaee-api) so you have other defaults than the one in tomee server.

Either set the system property to select the right one or use the right API dependency.